# Terraform filebase64 on pfx certificate difference vs azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvtcert.certificate_data_base64

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating self signed certificate in terraform by running the following code

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "kvtcert" {
  name         = "self-signed-${var.app_name}"
  key_vault_id = var.vault_id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      extended_key_usage = [
        "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1",
        "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2",
      ]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = [
          var.certificate_domain
        ]
      }

      subject            = "CN=${var.certificate_domain}"
      validity_in_months = 36
    }
  }
}
```

I am also outputing the value of

```
azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvtcert.certificate_data_base64
```

The value is the following

```
MIIDtTCCAp2gAwIBAgIQC0KMaP0rQvu7H2toNu4kajANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA5XX70XXXDEy5hZ2VXtqwez7X2XscX1XXtqNu4kXjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFXXX9XX7X50XXXNQYDVQQDEy5hZ2VXXXM-Xlqez2XtqXoNu4XXxcXXXXNzXtqNu4XXXXqMb4XDTIzXXY0NjE5NXXAZXDTI2MDXxXmIwMDAzM1owX9X703tUGA1UEAXXXuX5X-XXXXlX2-XXMDDUmXXXXXXXXXDPX9XXXXXzMiwiavxX5S8Xgc7XXXXXXXXIwDT7eyXGd1Tmf7XkVXXXXQvHTMXXnEXVbX-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
```

When I download pfx file from the kv of the certificate that was generated by terraform and run the following terraform code

```
output "XXX" {
   value = filebase64("${path.root}/../self_signed_certificate/self-signed.pfx")
}
```

I am getting the following value

```
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
```

The first value is much shorter, not to mention the final characters which are '=' and '=='.
My question is why the values are different.

Comment: The first value is the PEM encoded certificate, while the second value is the base64 encoded certificate. 
You can convert the PEM encoded certificate to base64 encoded certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> The first value is much shorter, not to mention the final characters which are '=' and '=='. My question is why the values are different.

If you check the certificate output value using a Terraform block, it will be displayed in `base64` format

```json
    output  "example_pem" {
    value  =  azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvtcert.certificate_data_base64
    }
```

[image]

If you want to check the downloaded certificate value, note that the default format of a `.pfx` file is not base64 encoded. Instead, it is typically encoded in `PKCS#12` format.

To check the same value, convert the `.pfx` file to the `.cert` format using the following command and then verify the value.

```
openssl x509 -in "C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\xyz.pfx" -out certificate.crt
```

```
                    OR
```

Download the `CERT` file from the Azure portal by following the steps below

[image]

After downloading the `CERT` file from the portal, you can check its value.

[image]